# How to determine the effective index of the fundamental mode?

Tags: fiber-optics

Suppose I have an optical fiber, the cladding refractive index n1 = 1.53 and the that of the core is n2 = 1.55. How to estimate the effective index? Is it right in between the two values?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Often the difference between an effective index of 1.55 and 1.53 is less than your uncertainty about the length of the fiber.

Answer (score 0):

Use the inner index. Light travels in the core. The purpose of the cladding is to act like a mirror and reflect light that is about to escape back into the core.

[Cladding (fiber optics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cladding_(fiber_optics))

[Fiber-Optic Technologies](https://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=170740&seqNum=3)

Comment: In a single mode fiber, a substantial portion of the power travels in the cladding.

Comment: @ThePhoton - I am not that familiar with the subject. But the Wikipedia article said that the cladding often has an overcoat so the light propagating in it disappears after a few cm. If this is not true for single mode fibers, I was wrong.

Comment: The overcoat is on the outer surface of the cladding. The light can be in the core and cladding and not penetrate substantially into the overcoat (and yes, if it did propagate in the overcoat that would cause strong attenuation). What they refer to as "light propagating in the cladding" means cladding modes (i.e. modes that have most of their power in the cladding), but OP asked about the fundamental mode.